# Integrating CKeditor to my symfony2 project

Tags: symfony, ckeditor

I was trying to integrate ckeditor to my symfony2 project so that some of the textarea will have the ckeditor html editor. I brought the ckeditor on my required textarea by calling the class="ckeditor" in my form. The issue that I am facing now is that when I use the ckeditor the submit button of my form will not work instead I will have to use the built in "Save" option of the ckeditor toolbar for submitting the form. When I remove the ckeditor from the textareas and use normal textarea the submit button seems to work.

I do not want to use the "Save" button on the ckeditor toolbar to submit my form. Is there a workaround to make the submit button work? Tried googling out for possible solutions but could not find any.

P.S: I would also like to know if there are other html text editors like ckeditor that would work well with symfony2 and link to implementation instructions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know what's going wrong with your form submission but I have created a bundle which allows you to integrate easily CKEditor in a Symfony2 project. The bundle is available [here](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle).

If you want to use an other wysiwyg editor, you can use TinyMCE which is available [here](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle).

If you are looking for some Symfony2 ressources, I recommend you to visit the [Knp Bundles website](http://bundles.knplabs.org) which lists the available Symfony2 bundles.

Comment: Thank you for the bundle for integrating CKEditor with Symfony.
I tried your bundle. it works.
But I'm new to both symfony and ckeditor. And I'm having a problem with the links given in "head" tag in html, which are related to ckeditor. All the needed links are excluding the "web" prefix like "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/bundles/ivoryckeditor/config.js?t=B8DJ5M3"></script>". And it cant find it there. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First my textarea was empty, and after filled the ckeditor field or even without, the submit button didn't do anything.

So I had to to push the save button of the toolbar.

But then i did 'previous page' and came back to the same page but with the field hydrated with the content a just send and THERE the submit button works!!

So i just tried to put a default text in the textarea and now there is no more problem with the submit button.

Comment: It's probably because you have some assert restrictions but ckeditor form filed doesn't show them

Answer (score 0):

Another Symfony2 Ckeditor bundle is the [TrsteelCkeditorBundle](https://github.com/trsteel88/TrsteelCkeditorBundle).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem but my current project prevents me from installing any bundles because I'm only integrating symfony 2 forms into a custom project. The reason behind the error is this:

CKEditor overrides the focus on the textarea which prevents sf2 validator to validate the form when you press Submit. The full error is similar with this one:

"An invalid form control with name='XXX[textarea_content]' is not focusable. "

I'm still searching for an elegant solution, my aim is to override CKEditor focus or fully remove it. Will get back to you once I have the solution.