# how can i use Tinymce in twig (symfony2)

Tags: symfony, tinymce

i want to use tinymce in my symfony project
befor i define this editor i can read from form and write to database
after i define tinymce and set selector to textarea  in above of my twig file

```
{# src/MY/FilmBundle/Resources/views/Page/newfilm.html.twig #}
{% extends 'MYFilmBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea"
        });
    </script>

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <form action="{{ path('MYFilmBundle_submitNewFilm') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="movie">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}


        {{ form_row(form.text)}}

        {{ form_rest(form) }}

        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'Submit'}}" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

and add this code to buildfilmform (php class) i cannot able to read from form

```
   class buildfilmform extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
          $builder->add('text', 'textarea')
        }

        public function getName()
        { // return a unique identifier
            return 'MY_filmbundle_buildfilmform';
        }
}
```

the action that reading the form and save to db:

```
public function submitNewFilmAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $newFilm = new Film();

    $user = $this->getUser();
    $user_obj = $em->getRepository('MYFilmBundle:Author')->find($user);

    $newFilm->setAuthor($user);

    $form = $this->createForm(new buildfilmform(), $newFilm);
    $form->bind($this->getRequest());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $film = $form->getData();

        $em->persist($film);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MYFilmBundle_homepage'));
    }


    return $this->render(
        'MYFilmBundle:Page:newfilm.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),

    ));
}
```

i dont know how can i able to use

```
// Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
console.debug(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());

// Get the raw contents of the currently active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});

// Get content of a specific editor:
tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent()
```

that was said in [tinymce site](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getContent)

can you help me?

thanks a lot

p.s : i added tinymce-dev to my project , i want to know how can i able to use the above code in my project

Comment: Is there any javascript errors being thrown or nothing at all?

Comment: nothing at all, i can see editor but i cant read any the data from it!

Comment: could you please a) fix the code in your question ... and b) tell us what exactly you're trying to achieve instead of throwing in random code pieces from the tinyMCE documentation? ... and maybe c) tell us which version of symfony you're using ? ... further d) how and where do you integrate the main javascript files of tinyMCE? :-)

Comment: thanks for your answer :) -a) yes sure, i'll edit the code but which part? b) i want to read the data from the tinymce but i don't know how can i use the code that available in tinymce site c)version: 2.2 d)i unzip and put the all folder of tinymce_3.5.8_dev in web folder of my symfony project

Comment: Just to be clear: What's your problem? TinyMCE isn't working or you're not able to read the content from the textarea in your controller?

Comment: isn't work! then i think maybe i'm not able to read! non of the 3 code that was in the tinymce site doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

:D its work :P
i change the textarea in the buildform

```
$builder->add('text', 'textarea')
```

to :

```
$builder->add('text', 'textarea', array('required'=>false));
```

this link explain clearly :)

[Can't submit a form with Symfony2 and TinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303431/cant-submit-a-form-with-symfony2-and-tinymce)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [TinymceBundle](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle), which makes it easy to define a textarea as a TinyMCE editor.

```php
$builder->add('introtext', 'textarea', array(
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'tinymce',
        'data-theme' => 'medium' // simple, advanced, bbcode
    )
));
```

Comment: i'm using it , but not working :( 
, my form haven't any action

Comment: Have you installed `stfalcon/tinymce-bundle` via composer? Have you installed the assets? Have you called `{{ tinymce_init() }}` inside a script tag? Read the instructions in the readme carefully.

Comment: yes i do - but i know,it's not obligatory , i found a link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303431/cant-submit-a-form-with-symfony2-and-tinymce , but now i don't know haw can i make it non required!

Answer (score -1):

Use [GenemuFormBundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle), it supports TinyMCE and has other neat form types, like Captcha, datepicker, colorpicker, autocomplete, rating, etc.